# Filtering on Many to Many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, lambda, linq-to-sql

I have 3 related entities with 1 to many relationships.
Account 1-*  Collection  1-*  items

Each of these has a many to many relationship with Users, (with join tables AccountManagers , CollectionManagers, ItemManagers)

I'm trying to get a list of Collections for a user if he's in any of the join tables.
I was thinking create 3 expressions and then merge the 3 results at the end and somehow remove duplicates.
It seemed like Lambda expressions are the way to go, but I'm still learning them.

I think the middle one is easier , like
db.Collections.where(C => C.CollectionManagers.UserID == CurrentUserID)

But how would you gather a list of collections from the users account manager and item manager entries?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume `CollectionManagers` is a list from the many to many so you need something more like `Collections.Where(c => c.CollectionManagers.Any(a => a.UserID == CurrentUserID))`.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you post the relevant part of the entity classes you are talking about (especially the navigation properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ, the `Union` operator will return only the unique Collection rows, so assembling each category and combining them should work.

For Items, I thought it would be most efficient to find all Items managed by the current user and then find all collections they belong to:

```
var iCollections = Items.Where(i => i.ItemManagers.Any(im => im.UserId == CurrentUserID)).SelectMany(i => Collections.Where(c => c.Items.Contains(i)));
```

It is also possible to do this the other way, e.g. find all Collections that contain an Item managed by the current user:

```
var iCollections = Collections.Where(c => c.Items.Any(i => i.ItemManagers.Any(im => im.UserId == CurrentUserID)));
```

For Collections, as you pointed out, you just need to find all collections where the current user manages the collection:

```
var cCollections = Collections.Where(c => c.CollectionManagers.Any(cm => cm.UserId == CurrentUserID));
```

For Accounts, we find all accounts managed by the current user and then all collections owned by the account:

```
var aCollections = Accounts.Where(a => a.AccountManagers.Any(am => am.UserId == CurrentUserID)).SelectMany(a => a.Collections);
```

Then you can `Union` the results together:

```
var CurrentUserCollections = iCollections.Union(cCollections).Union(aCollections);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realize you could put the "i" further inside other statements.   )).SelectMany(i => Collections.Where(c => c.Items.Contains(i)));

Comment: Remember a lambda is just a shorthand for a delegate which is just a shorthand for a function, and it has access to parent scopes just like a block.